# Reading button inputs on arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I've just started tinkering with the arduino and i'm getting my head around the basics. I have a push button hooked up so so i get a serial print when it's pushed.

```
int button = 3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW) {
    Serial.print("pressed\n");
  }
}
```

Now when the button is pressed it'll print `pressed` a bunch until released. Now my next step is hook up an LED and I want to use the button as a toggle. Press it the first time, it'll come on, press it a second, it'll turn off. But this will run hundreds of times while the button is pressed. How do I get around this? Thanks

```
int led = 5;
int button = 3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW) {
    Serial.print("pressed\n");
    toggleLed(led);
  }
}

int toggleLed(int led){
  if (digitalRead(led) == LOW) {
    Serial.print("set on");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  } else {
    Serial.print("set off");
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example code that comes with the Arduino IDE called the State Change Example.  Study it.  Basically you need to have a variable to remember the state of the button the last time you pressed it and you only react to changes in the button state.  Instead of running your code anytime the button pin IS low, you run your code anytime the button pin changes from high to low.

Comment: That would be **File > Examples > 02.Digital > StateChangeDetection**?